# turn on led connected on arduino after a given time

Tags: android, android-studio, time, timer, arduino

I have created an android app which is connected to an arduino. The project is pretty simple: On the app there is an on and off button which turn a led connected to the arduino on and off respectively... But I want to take it a step further... I'd like the user to be able to give the time that must pass until the led turns on... For example he dials 20 in his app, and after 20 minutes the led is turned on... I've thought of using already existing alarm apps and their code but my knowledge is not sufficient to handle them...Could you suggest me a more simple way to accomplish my idea...Is anyone aware of already existing similar projecs?

Any suggestion is appreciated!!!

Comment: Why dont you send a "timer"-Command to your Arduino and let a timer do this part?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Could you please be a little more specific? Is timer a function in JAVA? Any link would be really helpful!!

Comment: Arduino received command 'led on after 20 minutes'. That would be in C then. As you program the Arduino in C i suppose. But you could also lett your app wait 20 minutes before the app sends the normal 'led on' command. Then it would be in java yes.

Comment: @greenapps Yes, I'd prefer the 2nd option...Do you have any link in mind?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to execute code after some delay.

```
public void turnOnLED(int timeDelay){

  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        // Do something after timeDelay ms
     }
  },timeDelay);

}
```

Code inside the run() method will be executed after timeDelay in miliseconds

Answer (score 0):

You could also start a timer on your Arduino if you send a command with your app. A simple way to do this could be:

```
#define MAX_UNSIGNED_LONG 4294967295
unsigned long StartTime = MAX_UNSIGNED_LONG;
unsigned long DelayTime = 10000; //Your delay in ms

loop
{
  //Receive Commando from app ... your code here:
  //To start your "timer": StartTime = millis()
  //Stop it with: StartTime = MAX_UNSIGNED_LONG;

  //Check if your time is elapsed here:
  unsigned long ActualTime = millis();
  if (ActualTime > StartTime && ActualTime - StartTime >= DelayTime)
  {
    //Tur on your Light here
  }
}
```